# Best practices to persist data without a DB in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel, next.js13

I have a simple app don’t have a DB because there is no data I need to save other than some small things. For example: access tokens or functions that have timeouts that will trigger things in the future.

I can simply store them in a variable, but what if the server is being reset?
I am hosting on Vercel, is it something that might happen?

Are there good alternatives to save this kind of data without a DB?

Comment: you can store in local storage in browser if it is specific to user or create json file in vercel and store/read information from it or use gcp secret manger something.